# Serial USB port unstable

Tags: arduino, serial-port, usb, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to connect an Arduino to my MacBook using an FTDI board.

I can connect to the Arduino using Screen in OSX' Terminal.

I can choose the same port (only the cu version) in the Arduino IDE.   The problem is that the Arduino IDE programmer cannot connect, so I cannot upload to the Arduino.

The loop back test works just fine.

Sometimes the port stops being recognized by both Terminal and Arduino IDE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) includes major changes to the USB drivers which have caused various problems.  I recommend upgrading to the latest version of Mac OS X if you have not done so already.

Comment: I have done that, and no change. Any idea on how to fix this issue?